# Get older mac java version 1.8.0_161

Tags: java

I need to get this exact version of java on my new mac os. I cannot find it at:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/oracle-java-archive-downloads.html

Old machine:

```
cmuench:~$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html

Comment: Doesn't look like exact version. How do I get 1.8.0_161-b12

Comment: Why exactly this version?

Comment: This worked! It was slighly different version but works